# Which URL should be used for GET, PUT, and DELETE of a child resource?

Tags: http, rest, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

Say I have a resource `parent` which represents a set of data. A restful URL structure for something like this should be pretty straightforward:

- GET /api/parents - return collection of all parents
- GET /api/parents/1 - return parent with id = 1
- POST /api/parents - add a new parent to the collection
- PUT /api/parents/1 - update data in parent with id = 1
- DELETE /api/parents/1 - delete parent with id = 1

Now say that each `parent` is composed of a collection of `child` resources. Should the child resources id's be considered to have global or local scope? I believe the following 2 URL's are given:

- GET /api/parents/1/children - return collection of parent 1's children
- POST /api/parents/1/children - add new child to parent 1's collection

But what about GET, PUT and DELETE? Which of the following are appropriate?

- GET, PUT or DELETE /api/parents/44/children/6
- GET, PUT or DELETE /api/parents/children/6

It seems like it comes down to the uniqueness scope of the `child` resource's ID. Is the ID unique only within  the parent aggregate? Or is it unique among all children of all parents? Is one more correct than the other, or does it depend on the id uniqueness scope of the resources in question?

If example 1 is more appropriate than example 2, and parent with id = 44 does not have a child with id = 6 (say child id = 6 belongs to parent with id = 9), what HTTP response should be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@danludwig

i do not think it actually matters as far as URIs are just resource identifiers and all these user friendly hierarchies are important only for human beings... but in either case i'd ask question regarding this one "/api/parents/children/6", lets break it down:

- GET to "/api/parents/children/6" gives us child resource
- **GET to "/api/parents/children" what happens here? 404?**
- GET to "/api/parents" gives us all parents
- GET to "/api" hopefully home(or index) document with links to other, subordinated resources.

I think it's a good test when constructing hierarchical URIs. Just make sure that each segment is bound to particular resource and doesn't return 404.

Comment: Good point about going backwards through the URL, that should have occurred to me. Do you have an answer to the last paragraph in the question? If the child ID does not belong to the given parent ID, which HTTP response code is more appropriate? Should it be 404 for GET, PUT and DELETE, or are different codes more appropriate depending on the HTTP request method?

Comment: @danludwig 404 for sure. if resource can not be identified by specified URI 404 is only appropriate response. It doesn't matter for outside world how do you implement these relationships inside your implementation. but when you identify resource with URI it means that whole URI identifies actual resource and not it's segment. URI are opaque strings and thus are used as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the ID unique only within the parent aggregate? Or is it unique among all children of all parents?

This would depend on the possibility of a child being the cild of *one and only one* parent. If this is the case, then locally scoped IDs are possible.

If, on the other hand, a child can be child of *more than one parent*, gloabally scope IDs would be necessary.

Of course one can ask if a child which has a global ID can only exist 'below' a parent, or if such a child can be addressed with an URL that does not contain a parent.

Answer (score 0):

The `GET, PUT or DELETE /api/parents/44/children/6` URL looks to me as it indicates the relationship between the parent and child resources.

The only problem is you would need to know the parent id in order to work with a child resource.

An alterative would be to remove the 'parent' part of the URL all together: `GET, PUT or DELETE /api/children/6` and have a "link" attribute or element inside the child resource that provides a URL to its parent.

```
<child>
   <id>6</id>
   <link rel="parent" href="/api/parents/1" />
   ...
</child>
```

Comment: As to your alternative answer, the `child` resource only makes sense within the context of `parent`. In DDD terms, `child` is owned by the `parent` aggregate, and shouldn't be accessible outside of it.